# Custom geometry transformation distorts material

Tags: three.js

Custom geometry's mesh material gets distorted after applying matrix transformation to my custom geometry.

In the sample jsfiddle, I've included my custom `TorusGeometry`. My custom geometry is placed next to a built-in `CylinderGeometry`.

You can see the difference in material between these two meshes. If I remove the geometry transformation, both the mesh's materials look fine.

I guess, I'm messing the normals while doing matrix transformation, but not sure to fix it.

https://jsfiddle.net/arundhaj/nrdg2faL/

[image]

Comment: Well, you can't just placing two geometries generated with two different classes next to another and expect a continuous surface transitions. `TorusGeometry` and `CylinderGeometry` have their own generation logic which leads to different surface normals and vertices. It's best to generate your final geometry by a single custom generator (or by modeling it in a DCC tool in the first place).

Comment: No, it does have continuous surface transition. Issue happens only when I apply matrix transformation to my custom geometry. If you comment `appyMatrix` in the jsfiddle, you can notice material will look same, except without transformation.

Comment: I've commented out the usage of `applyMatrix()`. Still, it does not look right... https://jsfiddle.net/bh1g0c3m/

Comment: Maybe you can check my original jsfiddle again, I've added another `CylinderGeometry` at the other end. When you comment `applyMatrix`, you could see those two Meshes seamless.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the vertex normals on the caps of the torus. [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marquizzo/nh38byzu/), I added a `VertexNormalsHelper`, and you can see the normals at the caps don't point perpendicular to the face as they should.

Comment: I don't think this issue occurs because of cap normals, because, when I comment `applyMatrix()` this issue doesn't occur.